# ./configure, how to provide a different executable during the checking phase

Tags: configure

I am trying to install the MonoDevelop IDE from source.
One of its prerequisites is Mono 2.10.

Unfortunately the preinstalled mono runtime on my current Ubuntu system is 2.6.7.

I managed to make a parallel mono install on my system. It is located at `/opt/mono-2.10`.

Sadly, once I run the `./configure` script, it fails saying that the `/usr/bin/mono` executable is outdated (as well as other executables related to mono).

I would want to try to pass a different path to `./configure`, to point to my parallel mono install (`/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono`) etc.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could point to a location from where the source could be downloaded. Add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `/opt/mono-2.10/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`:

```
PATH=/opt/mono-2.10/bin:$PATH
./configure
make
```

This may not be enough. Typically `configure` scripts take additional settings in the form of `--with-…` options or environment variables. Run `./configure --help` to see the possibilities.